# Find length of biggest common contiguous subsequence in specific time complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, pseudocode

Suppose we have 2 sequences(Arrays) `A[1..m]` and `B[1..n]` of integers.

How can we find the length of the biggest common contiguous subsequence of `A` and `B` in O(nlogn + mlogm + k^2) where k is the number of (x, y) tuples where `A[x] = B[y]`?

---

This is an example input:

```
A={1,2,3,4,5}
B={2,4,5,9,11,20}
```

output: `2`

---

Note that it is not guaranteed that arrays are sorted:

```
A={2,7,1,8,11}
B={1,3,7,1,11,2}
```

output: `2`

Comment: Did you mean to say "longest common continuous subsequence"?

Comment: @Cythonista, rather "contiguous".

Comment: Are the sequences guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @trincot my bad. I meant continuous. I will edit it right now

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No they are not. sorry for confusing example. I will provide more information to the question. thank you for your comment

Comment: Isn't this the longest common substring problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring

Comment: @גלעדברקן I think the problem is the same but I wanted to know how we can do it in this particular time complexity. Thank you for mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's refer to those "tuples (x,y) where `A[x] == B[y]` as "correspondences".

A common subsequence, then, corresponds to a list of correspondences `C` where there is are no two correspondences `C[i]` and `C[j]` such that `C[i].x < C[j].x AND C[i].y > C[j].y` or vice-versa.

First, make a list of all correspondences, sorted by x then y.  We can easily do this within the required complexity.

Then, we will iterate through this list and determine, for each correspondence, the length of longest subsequence that *ends* with that correspondence.  The largest result is the problem solution.

We will maintain an array `BEST[y]` which stores, for each `y`, the best result so far where the final correspondence `c` has `c.y == y`.  Initially this is all zeros.

For each correspondence `c`:

1. Find the greatest `BEST[y]` such that `y <= c.y`, and add 1 to get the `result` for `c`.  Remember the largest of these results, as it will be the solution to the problem.
2. If `result > BEST[c.y]`, set `BEST[c.y] = result`

That's it... but, in order to meet your complexity requirement, that search in step (1) needs to be done in O(k) time, even if k is much smaller than max(y).  You can do that by keeping a list of the non-zero values instead of an array.  There can be at most k of those, so you can search and update the list in O(k) time easily.

If you keep those entries in a binary search tree, and additionally remember the maximum value in each subtree, then you can reduce the complexity to O( nlogn + mlogm + klogk ).

Comment: Doesn't creating `C` take O(nm) time?

Comment: No, there are a lot of ways to do it faster.  The easiest way within O(nlogn + mlogm + k) is to sort the indexes of `B` by their element and then do a binary search in that for each element of `A`.  If you use a stable sort, then you get the correspondences in the required order and don't have to resort anything.